# How to add folders into a git repo that I've opened in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried dragging and dropping my folder into the opened `git` repo in VS Code but it doesn't go into the repo but instead "the workspace"! Is there a way to do it, or possibly a workaround?

Comment: When you make any changes to the files inside the repo, you have to do a `git add folder/file`, then commit the change with `git commit -a -m "Learn some git dude!"` and finally push the changes with `git push origin master`. Look at atlassian docs for tutorial of how git works.

Comment: thanks a lot @Krishna ! but is there a way to do this through the VS Code GUI, instead of using the terminal ?

Comment: You can have a look at this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol although I suggest you to learn the commands as it will be in handy in the future